# Special format for chapter title

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I want to format my chapter title for example:

**"Chapter one: Introduction"**

I have a new command defined as the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt] {report}
\usepackage{thesis_packages}

\newcommand{\ch}[2]{ 
\setcounter{chapter}{#1}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\chapter*{#2}}

\begin{document}

\include{introduction}
\end{document}


% introduction.tex
\ch{1}{Chapter One: Introduction}   \label{ch:intro}
```

For that, I need to write \ch{1}{Chapter One:intro} in the introduction.tex file. However,I receive an error says "undefined control sequence \ch{1}{Chapter One:intro}".
The new command is defined in the main text file. I use report documentclass.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What have you tried? Which document class do you use?

Comment: @n.a.s: The update does not really clearify the problem. Do you use a `book` - like class at all, that has the `\chapter` command?

Comment: I am working on thesis, and I use report  class.

Comment: There's a `}` missing after `\chapter*{#2}`. The content of `introduction` is still hidden.

Comment: I really can't see what you want exactly: must your chapter be numbered or not?

Comment: Yes numbered and titled as I showed above.

Comment: The command you introduced is suicidal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\inletters}[1]{\ifcase \csname c@#1\endcsname
  zero\or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or six\or seven\or
  eight\or nine\or ten %complete here if you have more than 10 chapters 
  \else ??\fi} 

\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{\vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent\z@ \raggedright \normalfont\Huge\bfseries
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\m@ne \@chapapp~\inletters{chapter}: \fi
     #1\par\nobreak\vskip 40\p@}}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
    {\@chapapp~\inletters{chapter}: #1}% <-- modification
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
  \fi
  \chaptermark{#1}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
  \else
    \@makechapterhead{#2}%
    \@afterheading
  \fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

In this chapter, ...

\section{First section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This will print `one`, `two` etc. any occurence where `\thechapter` is expanded, i.e. in the ToC or in a reference

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Thank you for the comment.  This is corrected.

Comment: I can't upvote again, however ;-)

Comment: Thanks. How can I add the same chapter format in TOC?

Comment: @user94293 I tried your suggestion, it shows only number of chapter and the title. I want it to be similar to "Chapter One: Introduction" for instance. The word chapter also should be included!

Comment: @n.a.s: Done; definition of \@chapter was adapted.  See `<-- modification`

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your efforts. It works. However, I still search for an easier method:).

Answer (score 4):

The new command `\ch` seems to be unnecessary. To do what you want automatically, there are two things you need.

First, you need to print the chapter number in words instead of the usual numerals. To do this, load the `fmtcount` package. This will provide you with `\numberstring` and `\Numberstring` commands (for lowercase and capitalized respectively) to print the current value of a counter in words.

```
\usepackage{fmtcount}
```

Second, you need to slightly change the format of the chapter headings to put it all on one line. I expect there's a package for this purpose out there, but it's quite easy to do it by redefining `\@makechapterhead` yourself:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{\vspace *{50\p@ }{\parindent \z@ 
\raggedright \normalfont \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \Huge \bfseries 
\@chapapp \space \Numberstring{chapter} : \fi #1\par \nobreak \vskip 40\p@ }}
\makeatother
```

Then in the body of the document, you can use the `\chapter` command normally:

```
\chapter{First Chapter}

This is Chapter One.
```

[image: Chapter One: First Chapter [vertical space] This is Chapter One.]

Comment: +1 for the use of `fmtcount`

Comment: Thanks so much  Freind. Using fmtcount package is really helpful. The problem is when I use this code in my latex project, an error appears says" an extra \else in \include{introduction}. Also I don't want section numering to appear as "one.1 section name"?

Comment: A `\fi` is missing before `#1` in the definition of `\@makechapterhead`.

Comment: @n.a.s Sorry, I think those problems are corrected now. The first was due to the missing `\fi` pointed out above. The second was caused by `\thechapter` being used by the section commands.

Answer (score 2):

You simply can use the tools from `titlesec` which make formatting of section titles easy. What you want is the `block` style:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage[letterspace=30]{microtype}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\Huge\bfseries\lsstyle}{\chaptername~\Numberstring{chapter}:}{0.333em}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

In this chapter, ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have the same (almost ;o)) in the table of contents, you can use  `\titletoc`. As it gives access to the *string* `\thecontentslabel`, you have to convert this string to a number before you can use the `fmtcount` commands. This is done with one of the commands ending in `num` (`\Numberstringnum`, `\numberstringnum`, &c.):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[letterspace=30]{microtype}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\Huge\bfseries\lsstyle}{\chaptername~\Numberstring{chapter}:}{0.333em}{}

\titlecontents{chapter} [0em]{\bfseries} {\chaptername~the~Ordinalstringnum{\thecontentslabel}:\quad} 
{}{\hfill\contentspage} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}

In this chapter, ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernad. This code works perfectly, but when I paste the line[\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\Huge\bfseries\lsstyle}{\chaptername~\Numberstring{chapter}:}{0.333em}{}] into my main text file, I get an error: "undefined control sequence \chapter{introduction}".?

Comment: I used \titleformat[hang], and it works!. Thanks a lot. I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: `hang` is the default. The difference with `block` can be seen only with multilined titles. Actually, you're right, it's better than  `block`for flushleft titles. The latter should be used for centred or flushright titles.

Comment: Spacing lowercase? Oh, no! `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: I think for very big sizes in boldface, this is tolerable. I don't like so much kerning in big titles, but I don't know how to deactivate it, so letter spacing is a work-around – which I use very sparingly…

Comment: Do you mean the table of contents should contain ‘Chapter One: Introduction’ instead of ‘ 1 Introduction’?

Comment: I still need to add the same chapter format in TOC?

Comment: If you want to have the same text, you can use the `titletoc` package which comes with `titlesec`.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard. I used titletoc. I've added the same chapter format in  \titlecontents{chapter}
{\bfseries}
{\chaptername~\Numberstring{chapter}:\quad}
{\hfill\contentspage} ... The table of content numbers all chapters by Zero. Such as "Chapter Zero: introduction" , "Chapter Zero: Review",..etc. How can I fix this?

Comment: @n.a.s: The trick is to use a command which converts the string `\thecontentslabel` into a number, before formatting it. Please see my addition to the answer. Note you forgot two things in your code for `\titlecontents`: the first argument (between brackets) is not optional, mandatory, as explained in the doc, and you forgot the formatting commands for the `numberless` sections (mandatory, even if there's none).

Comment: Thanks. What is "Ordinalstringnum"?

Comment: It converts the chapter `number` (not the chapter `counter`) into an ordinal number, with the first letter capitalised. Here, the number 1 is changed to `First` (it takes the language declared by `babel` into account).

Comment: @Bernard, can you please upvote the question if you find it useful? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For reference/just for fun, here is how you can accomplish this in ConTeXt.

```
\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [conversion=Word,
   numbercommand=\NUMBERCOMMAND,
   style=\bfd]
\define[1] \NUMBERCOMMAND
  {Chapter #1:}

\starttext
  \chapter{Introduction}
  In this chapter, \periods
\stoptext
```

Comment: @9tTn98, can you please upvote the question if you find it useful? Thanks